# Sort two types of objects in a single array

Tags: javascript, sorting

I have an array with `meeting` objects having property `utc_start`.
I also have an array with `reminder` objects having property `utc_datetime`.

After combining them as such:

```
    combined = [];
    combined = combined.concat(meetings);
    combined = combined.concat(reminders);
```

Is it possible to sort them? Each by using the different property?

```
combined.sort((a, b) => {

});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just FWIW, rather than `concat`, you can use `combined = [...meetings, ...reminders]` in modern environments (ES2015+): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 4):

You can try with:

```
combined.sort((a, b) => {
  const utcA = a.utc_start || a.utc_datetime;
  const utcB = b.utc_start || b.utc_datetime;

  // compare utcA with utcB
});
```

Comment: ...assuming `0` isn't a valid value for `utc_start` (which seems like a valid assumption, unless these are time-of-day, and from their names I suspect they're either Dates or time-since-The-Epoch).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder OPs question is about getting the right information for the further comparasion. I don't even try to assume what those values are. ;-)

Comment: `a.utc_start || a.utc_datetime` assumes that `utc_start` will not be `0` on a meeting object. But again, to me, it seems like a safe assumption.

Comment: Thank you for this, however it is not achieving the desired sorting results. Please take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re7jar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html (Updated URL) `"2018-06-13T21:48:00.000Z` should come before `"2018-06-13T22:49:00.000Z"` correct?

Comment: @hsz actually please check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-re7jar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts It requires two iterations on `.sort` to output the desired sorting.